# AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_field_names'

Tags: django, django-admin, multilingual

I am trying to add `MultilingualModel` .
I am using 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multilingual-model/0.6

but i keep getting the error:

```
File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/multilingual_model/models.py", line 100, in __getattr__
translated_fields = self.translations.model._meta.get_all_field_names()
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute 'get_all_field_names'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem:-

```
translated_fields = [f.name for f in self.translations.model._meta.get_fields()]
```

This i have referred from the docs,

Hope this Helps :-)